# Button click data-bind is not working with knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I cannot get the following piece of code to fire the button click to call *save*. I am using ASP.Net MVC with Knockoutjs. I am new to knockout and mvc. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

**cshtml**

```
@section scripts
{        
  <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="~/CustomScripts/bookingviewmodel.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
       var bookingViewModel = new BookingViewModel(@Html.Raw(data));
       ko.applyBindings(bookingViewModel);
   </script>
}

<div class="content">
 <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-bind="click: save"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save Booking</button>
</div>
```

**bookingviewmodel.js**

```
BookingViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

    self.save = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Booking/Save",
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.bookingViewModel != null) {
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data.bookingViewModel, {}, self);
                }
            }
        });
    }  
}
```

Comment: I don't see a line here to apply the binding.  Did you do that in your code?

Comment: @coralv - the binding has been applied as mentioned the above cshtml section. have i done something wrong here?

Comment: No, sorry.  I wasn't looking for it there.  I didn't see it in the `bookingviewmodel.js` file and thought you'd missed it.  Not sure what is going wrong here in that case.

Comment: Is this all the code there is? If not; try to target on what you want to apply the binding. Depending on the page or other logic this could break things for you.